# Node JS, Redis and Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis

I have installed the redis module in my application `npm install redis`. Locally I can connect to that fine and write to redis like so

```
var redis = require('redis');
if(process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production') {
  var r_client = redis.createClient(process.env.REDISCLOUD_URL);
} else {
  var r_client = redis.createClient();
}

function writeToRedis(tweet, screen_name){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    r_client.hset(screen_name, 'tweet_id', tweet['id'], 'tweet_text', tweet['text'], 'avatar', tweet['user']['profile_image_url'], 'screen_name', tweet['user']['screen_name'], function (error, result) {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
        return;
      }
      resolve(result);
    });
  });
}
```

When I deploy to Heroku though and try to write to redis (I have installed the addon Redis Cloud) I get the following error

```
(node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): ReplyError: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hset' command
```

Is there another addon i should be using apart from Redis Cloud or have i done something wrong? I am confused as it works locally

Thanks

Comment: have you tried passing single key value instead of three key value pairs?

Comment: you have to use hmset for multiple key and values at once

Comment: @varnit ah yes... wonder why it works locally then.... And that has solved it... Thank you... my own fault for not reading the docs correctly

Comment: are you using different redis versions locally and on heroku?

Comment: and I'm posting the comment as answer please mark it as solved so others can get benefit form the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hset function in redis only allow one key value pair at once

```
client.hset("hash key", "hashtest 1", "some value", callback);
client.hset(["hash key", "hashtest 2", "some other value"], callback);
```

use hmset instead

```
client.hmset(["key", "test keys 1", "test val 1", "test keys 2", "test val 2"], function (err, res) {});
```